# How to limit video crop section for 10 seconds in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

[image]

I want to set the cropping section set to 10 seconds time. Is it possible to do with default image picker. Is it is how may I do it?

Comment: Try this.. `[imagePicker setVideoMaximumDuration:10.0f];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This code..

```
-(void)recordVideo{
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *) kUTTypeMPEG4, nil];
    imagePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720;
    [imagePicker setVideoMaximumDuration:10.0f];
    sourceType = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType];
    if (![sourceType containsObject:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie]) {
        NSLog(@"Can not Save Video");
    }
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

Make sure that, you have to set `allowsEditing` to `YES` before presenting the controller.